# MySql update syntax error from inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update, inner-join

```
UPDATE
    `universities`
SET
    `universities`.countryid = `countries`.id,
FROM
    `universities`
INNER JOIN
    `countries`
ON
    `universities`.country = `countries`.name
```

When I try to run the sql statements above via PhpMyAdmin, it would give syntax errors. I wrote the statements based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server/2334741#2334741).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the correct syntax in MySQL:

```
UPDATE universities u JOIN
       countries c
       ON u.country = c.name
    SET u.countryid = c.id;
```

In addition, I introduced table aliases (so the query is easier to write and to read) and removed an extraneous comma.

Comment: Weird how this one works but many other with a lot of upvotes don't.

Comment: because the other one is using mariadb, meanwhile you are using mysql.